# Screen reader and error messages

Tags: accessibility, validation

In general, how do you display client-side validation messages on a web page to make it easy to read out? Alerts are read out nice but are forbidden in the current design.

Comment: [This is a nice way.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710292/accessibility-in-javascript-form-validation/14712559#14712559) It isn't exactly what your asking but should apply.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a paragraph or similar (optionally invisible) with a role of alert.

```
<p id="error-msg" role="alert"></p>
```

When something goes wrong, put the text in the error-msg element, with Javascript of some description.

```
document.getElementById("error-msg").innerHTML="What are you doing you fool!";
```

Or something to that effect.

I believe this is what YouTube uses to let a user know when a new video in a playlist is loading.

Hope this helps.